# Stopping a service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to stop a running service, with a console program I've made.
This is my code:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(ServiceName, ".");
sc.Stop();
```

I then wait for the service status, to turn into Stopped, but this never happens.
It seems to have StopPending and never goto Stopped.
When I check Services.msc, it is listed as stopped, and in the taskmanager, the process is gone.

Will it stay on Pending forever? Am I doing something wrong?
I have the code for the service aswell, if I need to modify something there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

You may try [waiting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35st9aw1.aspx) after stopping the service:

```
sc.Stop();
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25));
```

The `WaitForStatus` method will wait for the service to reach the specified status or for the specified time-out to expire before returning.

Comment: Actually, this seemed to work. I was checking myself, with a while loop, asking sc.status. I don't know why that never changed from Pending. Changing to WaitForStatus fixed it.

Comment: @Nicolay, probably the status was cached. There is a `sc.Refresh()` method to update the status. But WaitForStatus is the better solution